# What is __peg_parser__ in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

I was using the [`keyword`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/keyword.html) built-in module to get a list of all the keywords of the current Python version. And this is what I did:

```
>>> import keyword
>>> print(keyword.kwlist)
['False', 'None', 'True', '__peg_parser__', 'and', 'as', 'assert', 'async', 'await', 'break', 'class', 'continue', 'def', 'del', 'elif', 'else', 'except', 'finally', 'for', 'from', 'global', 'if', 'import', 'in', 'is', 'lambda', 'nonlocal', 'not', 'or', 'pass', 'raise', 'return', 'try', 'while', 'with', 'yield']
```

And in the [`keyword.kwlist`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/keyword.html#keyword.kwlist) list there is `__peg_parser__`. So to see what it does, I type `__peg_parser__` in a Python 3.9 interpreter on Windows (you'll get the same output on Mac OS and Linux as well), and this is what is get:

```
>>> __peg_parser__
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    __peg_parser__
    ^
SyntaxError: You found it!
```

So my question is, what is `__peg_parser__` and why do I get `SyntaxError: You found it!`?

Comment: Have you tried reading this: https://bugs.python.org/issue40939

I think this is an old feature, but I am not able to digest the information there.

Comment: @deecue Thanks for the link, it seems like it is an Easter Egg that will be changed in Python 3.10

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It was an easter egg related to the rollout of [the new PEG parser](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0617/). The easter egg, along with the old LL(1) parser, [will be removed in 3.10](https://bugs.python.org/issue40939).

Answer (score 15):

Guido published on github [here](https://github.com/we-like-parsers/pegen) for the new PEG parser.

It's also on [Python PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0617/).

As it mentions:

> This PEP proposes replacing the current LL(1)-based parser of CPython with a new PEG-based parser. This new parser would allow the elimination of multiple "hacks" that exist in the current grammar to circumvent the LL(1)-limitation. It would substantially reduce the maintenance costs in some areas related to the compiling pipeline such as the grammar, the parser and the AST generation. The new PEG parser will also lift the LL(1) restriction on the current Python grammar.

Also mentioned in [Python 3.9 What's new](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#new-parser) page.

In Python 3.10, the `LL(1)` parser will be removed. Python 3.9 uses a new parser, based on PEG instead of LL(1).

In Python 3.6, it is not defined:

```
>>> __peg_parser__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    __peg_parser__
NameError: name '__peg_parser__' is not defined
>>>
```

Answer (score 11):

#### What is `__peg_parser__`?

It is an Easter Egg in Python (of the [Peg Parser](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0617/)) for when the new [Peg Parser](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0617/) was released. As mentioned in this [discussion](https://bugs.python.org/issue40939), it will be removed in Python 3.10.

Before the Easter Egg was called `__new_parser__`, but was changed to `__peg_parser__`, to make it future proof as mentioned in the [message](https://bugs.python.org/msg371265):

> `new`, `ex` or `ng` are not really future proof names. Can we rename the keyword to `__peg_parser__`?

#### Why do you get `SyntaxError: You found it!`?

You get `SyntaxError: You found it!` because it is part of the Easter Egg.

#### Will it be removed in the future?

Since the [LL(1) parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser) will be replaced be the new [Peg Parser](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0617/), it will be removed in Python 3.10.

#### `__peg_parser__` in Earlier and Later Versions of Python

It didn't exist in earlier versions of Python.

Python 3.8 and earlier:

```py
>>> __peg_parser__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '__peg_parser__' is not defined
```

Python 3.9:

```py
>>> __peg_parser__
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    __peg_parser__
    ^
SyntaxError: You found it!
```

Python 3.10:

```py
>>> __peg_parser__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '__peg_parser__' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2):

This PEP proposes replacing the current LL(1)-based parser of CPython with a new PEG-based parser. This new parser would allow the elimination of multiple "hacks" that exist in the current grammar to circumvent the LL(1)-limitation. It would substantially reduce the maintenance costs in some areas related to the compiling pipeline such as the grammar, the parser and the AST generation. The new PEG parser will also lift the LL(1) restriction on the current Python grammar.

[read more](https://github.com/we-like-parsers/pegen)